# AMD Crimson Driver 14.04 LTS Installation

Tags: drivers, software-installation, ati, gpu

I new to Linux and still learning how to use it.I have a R290 GPU and I need help in installing the new Crimson Drivers from AMD. I there a step by step guide in installing the drivers? I've been searching for a couple of hours but I only found the old catalyst drivers installation guide.

Answer (score 0):

Check this detailed answer I wrote :) If you don't have any bugs, you don't need to reinstall your system, just follow the step by step guide:

https://askubuntu.com/a/723364/488268